# How to find which application is using port 8080 and trying to connect open proxy?

Tags: port, irc

I am using [Hax-Chat](https://github.com/FutureHax/Hax-Chat) for my IRC but for few days I am having error of open proxy so I asked them they replied on of my application is using open proxy port 8080. So question is how could is find which one using it.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd prompt, enter

```
netstat
```

Voila.

Answer (score 0):

You could run an `lsof` command like this:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

Output would be something like this:

```
launchd      1           root   27u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c67f      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
launchd      1           root   28u  IPv4 0x71913d17d1e5d687      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
mysqld    1295           jake   10u  IPv4 0x71913d17ede9ce9f      0t0  TCP *:8889 (LISTEN)
httpd     1296           jake    5u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c23f      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
httpd     1298           jake    5u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c23f      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
httpd     1299           jake    5u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c23f      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
httpd     1300           jake    5u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c23f      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
httpd     1301           jake    5u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c23f      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
httpd     1302           jake    5u  IPv6 0x71913d17d1e5c23f      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)
```

The ports are listed on the right next to the `(LISTEN)` state. The application/process is in the first column and the user running the process is in the third column. In this case I am on Mac OS X 10.9.5 and running MAMP and have my CUPS printing interface available.

So in this case you can see that I have CUPS listening to `localhost:631` and then I have MySQL (`mysqld`) listening to `*.:8889` and Apache (`httpd`) listening to `*.:8888`.

If you wanted to simply grab info on who is listening to port `8080` specifically, you could run this variant of that command:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "8080"
```

For example if I ran that with `8889` looking for my MAMP MySQL server:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "8889"
```

This is what I would get:

```
mysqld    1295           jake   10u  IPv4 0x71913d17ede9ce9f      0t0  TCP *:8889 (LISTEN)
```